# Stop previous ajax when new request is made using ajax

Tags: ajax

I am using Toast tui calendar https://nhn.github.io/tui.calendar/latest/ and I have an issue with ajax calling. It works correct except one thing, when I try to get data with the same option more than one times returns the new response but also still return the data of the previous response. please help me how can i resolve that thank u.

I think that there is something that I've missed.

[image]

**controller**

```
public function getBookingSlot(Request $request){

        $userBookings = Booking::where('room_id',$request->room_id)->where('booking_status',1)->get();
       foreach($userBookings as $booking){
            $events []  = [
                'id'            => $booking->id,
                'calendarId'    => $booking->id,
                'title'         => 'Booked',
                'category'      => 'time',
                'dueDateClass'  => '',
                'start'         => $booking->start_datetime,
                'end'           => $booking->end_datetime,
            ];
        }

            return  \Response::json([
                'events' => $events ?? null
            ]);
    }
```

**html view**

```
                 <div class="card mb-5 ">
                   <div id="calendar" style="height: 800px;"></div>
                 </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(".butonSubmit").click(function(){

        if($(".carousel-item").hasClass('active') ){
            let room_id = $(".carousel-item.active").find('.room_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('get-booking-slot')}}",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            room_id:room_id,
        },
        success:function(response){

            calendar.createSchedules(
            result = response.events
            );
            console.log(result);

        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        });
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you do not update the calendar after new request. Previous values are still there on the calender

Comment: please can you guide me a/c to my code ? thank u.

Comment: https://ibb.co/PCRGBnt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).